# Way to efficiently do SQL query or join in POSTGRES?

Tags: sql, postgresql

It may be similar to previous questions, but it is slightly different ( it has now field id variable)

I have the following tables.

table 1

```
 ID1   YEAR1        
 1      1980  
 2      1964 
 3      1910
```

and table 2

```
 ID2  YEAR2   VALUE FIELD ID
 1     2000     A     324
 1     1900     B     345
 2     1950     C     123
 2     1900     B     324
 3     2000     C     123
 3     1970     B     444
 4     1900     D     324
 4     1800     E     123
```

I would like to join / query these tables to:

For each ID1 in table 1 match, add a column named VALUE - so the column names would be A, B, ... and so on, and the column would be either TRUE(T) or FALSE(F).

The column A ... would be TRUE, if there was ID1 matching ID2 from table 2, and the YEAR2 for that given row in table 2 which matched ID2 was less than YEAR1 from that table 1 having given id1, and VALUE from row having ID2 from table 2 had A and the FIELD ID was either 324 or 123

So the resultant table would be as follows:

```
ID1   YEAR1     A   B   C   D   E         

 1      1980    F   F   F   F   F 
 2      1964    F   T   T   F   F 
 3      1910    F   F   F   F   F
```

...

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you try using CROSS JOIN and CASE WHEN to solve the problem?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question that you posted only 1 hour prior.  Voting to close.

Comment: If I may suggest read it carefully, you will see then there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.id1,
       t1.year1,
       CASE WHEN t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND t2.value = 'A' AND t2.year2 <= t1.year1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS A,
       CASE WHEN t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND t2.value = 'B' AND t2.year2 <= t1.year1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS B,
       CASE WHEN t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND t2.value = 'C' AND t2.year2 <= t1.year1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS C,
       CASE WHEN t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND t2.value = 'D' AND t2.year2 <= t1.year1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS D,
       CASE WHEN t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND t2.value = 'E' AND t2.year2 <= t1.year1 THEN 'T' ELSE 'F' END AS E
  FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN
       table2 t2
    ON t1.id1 = t2.id2;
```

Comment: Thank youHow about the field ID part?